# MVC Displaying a drop down box if object has a certain property value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, html-helper, dropdownbox

I have a property called FitToPlay and it contains a list of Players that are not injured.  What I want to do is make a drop down box for each position in a team and only fill the drop down box with the players in the fit to play list that have the position in question as either their primary or secondary position.

What I want to know is how can I just display specific objects using html drop down box helper.

Many thanks in advance.

J

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to loop through each position and inside the loop go through all the currently FitToPlay players and if either his first or secondary position is the currently looped through position then insert him into it.. in the end if someone was inserted create a dropdownlist

So something like..

```
//Loop through all the positions
foreach (var position in Model.positions)
{
   //Create a list for each position 
   List<SelectListItem> playersInPosition = new List<SelectListItem>();
   //Only loop through players with the current position as either primary or secondary
   foreach(var player in Model.FitToPlay.Where(pl => pl.primary == position || pl.secondary == position))
   {
     //Put this player into the list
     playersInPosition.add(new SelectListItem { Text = player.name, Value = player.id});
   }
   //If at least one fits the criteria make a drop down list from it
   if(playersInPosition != null && playersInPosition.Count > 0)
   {
       @Html.DropDownList(position.name, playersInPosition);
   }
}
```